# RoR: Javascript call + page update in controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to implement the following function in a Rails controller:

```
"jQuery(document).ajaxStop(jQuery.unblockUI);"
 # "unblocks" a blocked DIV
```

In the controller, I have so far...

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html 'my_div', :partial => 'my_partial'
  [...]
  page.call 'jQuery.unblockUI()'   # this is the line...
end
```

...but this does not work. What's wrong? And what's the solution to this?

Thanks a lot for any hints and help with this!
Tom

===
Edit: Is there maybe a conflict between "render :update do |page| ..." and "page.call ..." ?
Edit 2: By "does not work", I mean: the controller gets executed normally, the DIV "my_div" gets replaced normally, but the "blocked" DIV does not get "unblocked". And Firebug does not indicate any error in the console...

Comment: Why don't you just send back a js.erb template and do your JavaScript from there?

Comment: @Samo : Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that!

Answer (score 0):

The function you are calling in the controller are calling [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) functions. You need to install [jRails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) to make it work with jQuery.